# How can I call the constructor before deserialisation?

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, datacontractjsonserializer

I try to serialize and deserialize a custom class via Data Contract Serialization.
The serialization works great. However, when deserializing, I run into a problem, because of this ([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6exf3h2k(v=vs.110).aspx)):

> Constructors are not called when objects are deserialized.

The thing is that I do a bit of initialisation in the constructor.
That includes some  data structures.

Without the call to the constructor, the data structures are `null` and the calls to setter functions during deserialisation fail.

**How can I call the constructor or initialize the object before or during the deserialisation process, before any accessor is used?**

There are a few methods that I can declare as callbacks via attributes, like this (same source):

```
// This method is called after the object 
// is completely deserialized. Use it instead of the
// constructror.
[OnDeserialized] 
void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
{
    fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

But it looks like they are all triggered **after** the deserialisation.

**Do I have to switch to XML Serialization?**

Comment: This should already have happened *before* you serialized the object.  So doing it again would be wrong.

Comment: Yes, Use `OnDeserialized` method where you can initialize your fields. Nothing could have accessed the fields/properties before that.

Comment: @HansPassant the deserialisation happens independently. Within the execution of the program, I only load the serialised data and want to deserialise it into an object. The serialisation isn't even happening before the deserialisation (in this instance of the program). I'm not quite sure how I would call the constructor before that.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel this is not correct. Again, the comments state that it happens **after** the deserialisation and my results agree with that: the accessors are used before the function is called. I cannot use it to initialise the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a constructor with the signature

```
protected YourClassName(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
}
```

and have your class implement `ISerializable`. On serialization it calls `ISerializable.GetObjectData()` on de-serialization it calls the above constructor.

See [Custom Serialization: Implementing the ISerializable Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) on the MSDN

If you don't actually need a to do the work in the constructor you can use the attribute [`[OnDeserializing]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializingattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `[OnDeserialized]` to get the work done *before* deserialization instead of after.

```
[OnDeserializing]
private void SetValuesOnDeserializing(StreamingContext context)
{
    // Code not shown.
}
```

Note: If you have more than one `[OnDeserializing]` method in your object graph the order they are called in is not dertimistic.

Comment: [The documentation lies when it says that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6exf3h2k(v=vs.110).aspx) "*Any given type can support none, one, or more of the serialization technologies.*", because  I cannot implement `ISerializable` and use the `DataContractAttribute` at the same time. `[OnDeserializing]` on the other hand works great. Thanks